# Installing Ubuntu 15.04 on mac book pro Yosemite

Tags: dual-boot, mac

I have mac book pro core I5 with OS X Yosemite 
and I created bootable USB drive and installed Ubuntu 15.04 using terminal 
and the rebooted the laptop and started Ubuntu through the usb flash drive PNY 16G USB.3 and while I was trying to download it after choosing the option of "running Ubuntu without installing" and it goes smoothly until I choose the option to have Ubuntu and third party alongside OS X but it will just freeze after couple of seconds, I tried multiple times But same  response
appreciate any help
thanks!!!

Comment: I'm having same problem. I tried installing with out those two checkboxes checked and it went fine, HOWEVER, there was not Install along side OS X option.  Just a wipe disk option, which I do not want to do.  Still searching for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem 
All you have to do is go to disk utility on ur mac and creat a partition and u can make what ever ext4,Ntfs and then when u get to the window where it says install as a third party DO NOT check the box and continue 
Its gonna show the the new partition u created and now u can format ot to ext4 with "/" as in extension and u can also creat a "swap" space which will give u extra space for memory in case ur RAM is all occupied
And that will be NOT a Primary  partition but logical and then u can install ubuntu on it
U have search how to make ubuntu bootable on you tube u will find it